# where do i find the MSF Agile 5.0 Process Template for TFS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, process, templates, agile

Hi Can anyone tell me where to download the new MSF Agile 5.0 Process Template for TFS 2010? I recently decided to use TFS 2010 server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A beta version of that process template should already be installed on the TFS 2010 Beta 1 server and you will be able to download it from the server using Team, Process Template Manager in Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1.

You may be able to download the process template separately once it is finished, but my understanding is that the development of the V5.0 version of that template is being done in the same timeline as the rest of the Visual Studio 2010 development.